# Multiple linear regression, fMRI

Tags: linear-regression

Say I have an fMRI experiment where I have a task that is suppose to measure response time, and the corresponding "activation" in the brain. I then have participants complete this task. Then I measure some variables through tests or assessments, and questionaries such as IQ, working memory, age, and years of education.

In fMRI experiments, as I am aware typically voxels (the name for the 3d fmri representation of a pixel) that remain "active" after statistical tests, while the participant completes a task, say something about how that brain region where those voxels are modulates that cognitive task.

Now, what if I want to use the variables that I measured, IQ, age, working memory, and years of education in a multiple linear regression test, with the brain activation to this task as the response variable, or dependent variable. What does this tell me?

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, it will give you a equation (less error relative to data-set presumed to be correct equation). Depending on data-set, equation has constants value for each variables which will provides the ratio of one variable with other variables.
You might find equation on similar format as this:

```
y = (b0 + b1.x1 + b2.x2 + b3.x3) + c
```

where ***x1***  , ***x2*** , ***x3*** can be different characteristics (as variables which can be *IQ, age, working momory, etc.*) and ***b0*** , ***b1***, ***b2***, ***b3*** are the constant calculated from given data-set.

You can find exact value of ***y*** or ***x1*** or ***x2*** or ***x3*** if you have exact value of other ***3*** variables.

Lets say, it was the data-set provided to an android/robot as in sci-fi movies; that android/robot will make it's decision based on this equation as ***law/fact/pattern*** and judge a person response time (if every other variables are known) or IQ (if every other variables are known) etc. by this equation.

There is also a lot of details in [this](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/284).

Note: This logic will only practical with Multiple Linear Regression Method.